# How to get 1 row per user with INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, distinct, resultset

I have two tables one is `user` and another is `images`. I gave users the option to select multiple images.  I can store multiple images with same `user_id` in database, but when I am trying to get one image from every user I am getting all the images.

My query is something like this:

```
$query = "
SELECT * 
  FROM images i
  JOIN users u
    ON u.user_id = i.user_id 
 LIMIT 1";
```

When I run this query in `while()` loop, I only get very first image from `images` table.

I am really sorry if I am not able to clarify what I am try to ask.

Comment: 'In a loop' ???

Comment: Yes because i wants to fetch all users from database  and wants to display all the users on index page. so i guess i do need while(mysqli_fect_array($results)). I hope you get it

Comment: You don't run the query in a loop. You parse the result in a loop. In your case, you only get one row in that result - because you only asked for one row.

Comment: yup i guess i used word query instead of results what i meant to be query or result was while($row = mysqli_fetch($result))

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users u INNER JOIN images i ON u.user_id = i.user_id GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

This should return you only one record from user/image tables for each user that has an image.

Don't run queries in a while loop. Instead, use one query to get all the desired records.

If you insist on running your query in a loop, then you are missing `WHERE users.user_id = ?` part in your query, so you can get a different result for each user in a loop.

Comment: You saved my day man thanks a lot it worked like charm. I am quite a bit new to PHP if your really don't mind to explain what this "GROUP BY" did to this query. I was trying to figure out on my own but i failed.

Comment: `GROUP BY` is grouping your results by `user_id` in this case and returns one record for each `user_id`. Try the query without `GROUP BY` and see what happens.

Comment: @NaveenKumar There is no 'day-saving' here. There is no problem in SQL for which the query above is a solution.

Comment: This will fail by default on a new MySQL install. And which image that is returned for each user is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this without using join. simple select user and fetch data and on the bases of 'id' add query to get image. i hope this will help you;

Comment: I guess you are talking about a specific id in users table but here  i want to fetch all the users. If you think so then please can you write down a query.

Comment: no you can select all user from table then when you fetch all you'll make another query on the bases of id to  images table you can set limit 1 there
"select * from images where user_id=$fr['id']"; where $fr is fetch result;

Comment: While this is entirely possible, it is likely to be hideously inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your current query:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM images i
JOIN users u
ON u.user_id = i.user_id 
LIMIT 1
```

uses LIMIT 1. This tells the query to bring back 1 row.

Removing the LIMIT 1 will return 1 or more records per user (who has at least 1 image), one for each image.

If you want a single user then it is possible (although not recommended) to (ab)use the GROUP BY clause:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM images i
JOIN users u
ON u.user_id = i.user_id 
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

This would bring back one record per user, but which image it returns is not defined. It could bring back the first image for that user, or the last one, or any other one (and which one it returns could change in the future). Further, there is no actual reason it couldn't return values from different rows for each of the columns on the images table (unlikely, but nothing specified to stop this happening).

Note that basic SQL standards specify (with a small exception) that any non aggregate field brought back in a SELECT statement must be in the GROUP BY clause. MySQL used to not enforce this restriction by default, but recently this changed and it is enforced by default. As such by default this query would no longer work as it is returning all the fields from the images and users tables while only specifying the user_id from the users table in the GROUP BY clause.

What you should do is define which image you want for each user. Assuming the first image (and that the images table uses an auto increment primary key called id):-

```
SELECT u.*,
        i.*
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id
            MIN(id) AS first_image_id 
    FROM images
    GROUP BY user_id
) sub0
ON u.user_id = sub0.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN images i
ON sub0.user_id = i.user_id AND sub0.first_image_id = i.id
```

This uses a sub query to get the first image id for each user. Then that is joined to the images table to get the other details for that image from the images table.

Note I have used LEFT OUTER JOIN. This is to return a row for a user who doesn't have any images uploaded.

Note it is generally a bad idea to use SELECT *, rather than specifying the columns to be returned. I have left this in place here as I do not know the column names of your tables.